# grep -l and grep -ln

Tags: unix, grep

according to the manual for grep,

```
-l, --files-with-matches
          Suppress normal output; instead print the  name  of  each  input
          file  from  which  output would normally have been printed.  The
          scanning will stop on the first match.
```

`grep -l`, this seems fine in that when a match is found, the file name containing the match is echoed.

However when i do a `grep -ln`, grep echoes every line of the occurrence.

Does `grep -l` really mean to stop when the first occurrence of the match is found and stop scanning, while `grep -ln` will ignore the `-l` flag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those options are incompatible. Use `grep -Hnm 1` if you want to display the line number of the first match (and only the first match) in each file.

> **-H, --with-filename**
>   Print the filename for each match.
>
> **-n, --line-number**
>   Prefix each line of output with the line number within its input file.
>
> **-m *NUM*, --max-count=*NUM***
>   Stop reading a file after *NUM* matching lines.